# UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Edge Insets not getting recognized by sizeForItemAt function?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So as the title suggest, I seem to have run into a weird problem. All I am trying to do here is create a 2 column collectionview without hardcoding anything into my delegate methods. Upon debugging I found that insetForSectionAt is called after sizeForItemAt, hence the custom insets are not taken into consideration when calculating the size of every cell.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    print("left: ", flowLayout.sectionInset.left)   // Prints out 0.0
    print("right: ", flowLayout.sectionInset.right) // Prints out 0.0
    let marginsAndInsets = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (cellsPerRow - 1)
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / cellsPerRow
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}
}
```

This problem can be solved very uglily by hard coding the values directly into the itemWidth variable as such, -20 because i know the values of left and right insets, 10 + 10

```
let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets - 20) / cellsPerRow
```

however, I have to believe that there is a better way of doing this, how can I call reloadData upon completion of the UIEdgeInset calculation so that my cells are properly sized?

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I ended up doing, i just added the customizations directly when creating the sizes for the collectionView and its cells.

```
class PinController: UICollectionViewController {

fileprivate let pinCellId = "pinCellId"
fileprivate let cellsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
fileprivate let margin: CGFloat = 10.0
fileprivate let topMargin: CGFloat = 2.0
}


extension PinController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let flowLayout = customize(collectionViewLayout, margin: margin)
    let itemWidth = cellWidth(collectionView, layout: flowLayout, cellsPerRow: cellsPerRow)
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth * 1.1)
}

/*
 Customizes the layout of a collectionView with space to the left and right of each cell that is 
 specified with the parameter margin
*/
private func customize(_ collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, margin: CGFloat) -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    // Interitem spacing affects the horrizontal spacing between cells
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = margin
    // Line spacing affects the vertical space between cells
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = margin
    // Section insets affect the entire container for the collectionView cells
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topMargin, left: margin, bottom: 0, right: margin)
    return flowLayout
}

/*
 Calculates the proper size of an individual cell with the specified number of cells in a row desired,
 along with the layout of the collectionView
 */
private func cellWidth(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout, cellsPerRow: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    // Calculate the ammount of "horizontal space" that will be needed in a row
    let marginsAndInsets = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (cellsPerRow - 1)
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / cellsPerRow
    return itemWidth
}
}
```